Как сделать простой Переход сцены для всех клиентов в сервере Unity Mirror
Уже много где поискал, в частности на английском комьюнити но так и не нашел. Я новичок в Mirror и столкнулся с такой задачей когда в сервере будет 2 клиента то надо перейти c сцены  Главного Меню в другую сцену где игроки между собой соревнуются. но когда делаю такой скрипт :
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine;

public class customNetManager : NetworkManager
{
    public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
    {
        base.OnServerConnect(conn);
        if (NetworkServer.connections.Count == 2)
        {
           Debug.Log("2 players!");
           ServerChangeScene("GameScene");
        }
    }
}

когда запускаю таким то у меня только сцена хоста меняется а у других клиентов сцена остается так же. в документации написано что ServerChangeScene() меняет сцену сервера и клиентов во всей сети. но у меня на клиентах оно не меняется.
почему? и как решить эту проблему?
